# Connect two applications

Tags: java, python, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I need to connect two application when they are are running: CMU Sphinx4 and a program written in python.

I don't want to integrate, only communicate between both apps.

I want to pass the line that was recognized by Sphinx to a `.py` file.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can write the info into a file and that the python app reads the file, you can send a TCP/IP or UDP network frame to start the interaction, you can use pipes, you can even connect them by using a database (it would be more complex though).

Comment: Look into inter-process communication. There are myriad ways to do this.

Comment: mmap, sockets, pipes, but just writing and reading a dumb old file will be by far the easiest, and for all practical purposes, plenty fast enough.